# Matching Month and Year in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access Database and I am working with two of the tables: *tbl_ProductionTarget* and *tbl_DailyInput*. I need to match the *tbl_DailyInputDate* to the target for that month.

The problem is that the targets are only updated once a month but the rest of the data is entered daily. How do I make my query only match the month and year from the daily input to the target table. I am adding the SQL code because I thought that would be easier for you to see what I am doing (or not doing).

PS. The total good parts is what I am trying to compare to the target but I don't think it is relevant to what I'm asking here.

```
SELECT tbl_ProductionTarget.Target_Hardening, tbl_DailyInput.TotalGoodParts
FROM tbl_DailyInput, tbl_ProductionTarget
WHERE (((Year([tbl_DailyInput]! 
[DailyInputDate]))=Year([tbl_ProductionTarget]![Target_Date])) AND 
((Month([tbl_DailyInput]![DailyInputDate]))=Month([tbl_ProductionTarget]! 
[Target_Date])));
```

Comment: The error is that I am getting an empty query result. I need to compare every daily record that is returned, using the parameters I have set to chose the date for those daily records, to the target that has been set for that month. Also, I don't know how I would relate the tables other than by the date.

Comment: If you receive zero records from this, either one or both the date fields are not true dates, or you simply have no matching records. In fact, you should receive a multiplum of records.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with exact query at least with my random data using 2018 dates. As @Gustav mentions, if no matches align there are no matches at all by month and year.

Comment: I found my answer Parfait but thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: @Gustav 
Thank you so much! Your mention of wrong dates made me look at my tables again. I looked back at my Target table and I had my dates formatted wrong. It was that simple.

Comment: Sounds like you store the dates as _Short Text_. Don't do that, use _Date_ or you will run into endless troubles.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to make a good suggestion without seeing your data, or at least the structure/data-types used by your tables.

You could rewrite your query to the following -

```
SELECT b.Target_Hardening, a.TotalGoodParts
FROM 
(
    SELECT TotalGoodParts, Year(DailyInputDate) AS Y, Month(DailyInputDate) AS M
    FROM tbl_DailyInput
) AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Target_Hardening, Year(Target_Date) AS Y, Month(Target_Date) AS M
    FROM tbl_ProductionTarget
) AS b
ON a.Y = b.Y AND a.M = b.M
```

But this is essentially a rephrasing of what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct but my dates were not formatted the same in each table. Once I fixed that, my query produced the correct results. Thank you Gustav.